# What is the deal with lodash@'~2.4.1'?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Tried to install some module and found the following warning. Tried to install lodash2.4.1 according its complaints but did not solve the problem.

```
$ npm install --save passport
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-            disk/node_modules/waterline-criteria requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-disk/node_modules/waterline-cursor requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
passport@0.2.1 node_modules/passport
├── pause@0.0.1
└── passport-strategy@1.0.0

$ npm install --save lodash@'~2.4.1'
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-disk/node_modules/waterline-criteria requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-disk/node_modules/waterline-cursor requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
lodash@2.4.1 node_modules/lodash

$ npm install
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-disk/node_modules/waterline-criteria requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/windchime/Development/moomu/node_modules/sails-disk/node_modules/waterline-cursor requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
```

Comment: It's warning for sails-disk dependency. The lodash that you installed yourself will be your project's dependency no the sails-disk dependency. Try reinstalling sails-disk may solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the comment posted above, reinstalling sails-disk solved the problem.

Comment: Congratulations.